# Format static url's in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have following code:

```
def create_student(self):
    if(user_passed == 's'):
        url = url + '/school'
    elif(user_passed == 'c'):
        url = url + '/school/' + self.school_name + '/class'
    elif(user_passed == 'st'):
        url = url + '/student'


def delete_student(self):
    if(user_passed == 's'):
        url = url + '/school/' + self.school_name
    elif(user_passed == 'c'):
        url = url + '/school/' + self.school_name + '/class' + self.class_type
```

... so on..

I am new to Python and wondering is there a better way to do this? I cannot change url's most of them are static.
I tried searching on google and stackoverflow but did not find anything related.

Comment: Where are you getting `user_passed` from?

Comment: @AChampion - these are from user through a gui.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use dict, and directly access the dict through `user_passed` variable as key. Something like this:

```
  data=   {"s": url+"/school", "c": url + '/school/' + self.school_name + '/class', "st":url + '/student'}
```

Now you can access them like this, since you would know the `user_passed` variable, simply pass:

```
try: 
   url = data[user_passed]
except: 
   print("wrong user_passed variable")
```

Hope this is a better solution for you.

Comment: If each have their own exception? Won't using list become more cumbersome?

Comment: It's not a `list`, it's a dict, you can set the user_passed` as key, so you would just have to do `url = data[user_passed], no matter what you have. No `if and else`.

Comment: There is another problem i get error when self.school_name is empty? can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str.

Comment: if `self.school_name` is not defined, then you're expected to get this error.

Comment: these are user give values, can be none sometimes. Is there any better way to do this then? Or I will have to go back to if/else?

Comment: if `self.school_name` is `None` then you won't need the url right?

Comment: There are other self.student_name commands too, that can be passed also. So that is not totally correct.